Rate of change of surface area is acting weird
Preface- I made this situation up. An uniform metal sphere of given mass $M$, is being continuously fed more mass at its centre at the rate $4 \  \text{kg/s}$. If the density stays constant, find the rate of increase in surface area.
How I tried to solve this
$$\rho V=M\implies \rho \frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dM}{dt}$$
So
$$4π\rho r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}=4\implies \frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{1}{π\rho r^2}$$
From here we can easily derive that $\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{8}{\rho r}$ using $A=4πr^2$
But we see that rate of increase in surface area is inversely proportional to that of the radius, so if radius increases, will the surface area increase at a slower rate? I can't actually visualise this, and so I can't analyse or make a diagram
Are my methods wrong?

You are constantly adding 4kg of mass and the density remains the same. The extra volume added stays constant. Imagine adding the mass as an extra shell on the outside of the sphere with an inner and outer radius. When the radius is small, to add the extra volume, a thick shell will have to be used. The change in surface area will be larger. As your sphere's radius is larger, the additional shell will be thinner, and so there will a smaller change in the surface area.
Imagine the same situation using a 2d surface (i.e., A disc being expanded). When the radius is small, the added rings on the outside will be more like a flattened torus (donut-shape). As the radius increases, to add the same area (the equivalent of volume from the original question), a thin rubber band like ring will do. Thus, the increase in circumference (equivalent of surface area) is more when the radius is smaller.
